# Is it possible to invoke @beforeclass in another class without extending in current testng class

Tags: java, testng

Out of curiosity I am asking this.

I am creating a test class with uses only @test @beforemethod and @aftermethod.

Creating another class and writing down codes for @beforeclass.

I understand only if I extend the class I can use @beforeclass on run time.

```
class a{
@beforeClass
Void m1() {} 
}

class B extends A{
@test
Void m2() {
}
}
```

My question--is it possible to un the @beforeclass without extending in class B??

Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: You can directly write @beforeClass in class B, there is no need to create a extra class A for the same.

Please point out if I understood the question wrong

Comment: No i will be creating 200 test cases which will use the @beforeclass from class A. Having it in same classes will create duplicate codes based on my scenario.